# Reboot instead of shutdown Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, shutdown, bios

As the title suggests, when I try to shutdown my computer from Ubuntu 12.04, it shuts down but then powers back on about three seconds later. I've changed my Grub settings and added:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=noirq"
```

But still the same problem. As a result, the only way I am able to shutdown my computer is to go to the BIOS after the restart and press the power button. Maybe it's my BIOS? I have a GIGABYTE GA-Z87X-UD3H, It's not the biggest deal, but any help resolving the problem would be much appreciated.

p.s. `sudo shutdown -h now` does not work either. plus, I would like more of an elegant solution as this is a family computer.

Comment: Try sudo shutdown -h 0

Comment: it is a rather well known bug. and it is hardware related. Can you check if WOL is enabled in BIOS? and if so disable it and try again.

Comment: Can you find the bug on luanchpad so I can add myself as being affected? My Thinkpad E530 does this and it's pretty annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Wake-up On LAN (WOL) is enabled in BIOS and it seems to be a bug  with power management. Turning of WOL in the BIOS should fix this. What seems to happen is that the system falsely identifies the shutdown as a power failure and it trigger WOL to start a reboot.

---

- [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/377/) has a topic on this specific board.
- [Arch BBS](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172028) too but it also has a claim about the power supply:

> My power supply was 450W. However, I got tired of going around the head until I read on page 23 of the GA-Z87N-WIFI manual which case we use the PCI-E was advisable to use a power supply of 500W or higher, as lower springs would destabilize (possible cause of the reboot).